# Is it possible to mark changed buffers in emacs speedbar

Tags: emacs, emacs-speedbar

I have started using speed bar in emacs and I would like to know if it is possible to mark (in the speedbar) the files / buffers that have unsaved changes.

Comment: Do you want the speedbar to automatically display buffers that have modifications? Or do you want to manually "mark" buffers in speedbar?

Comment: I would like speedbar to update the lines of buffers that have modifications with some kind of mark. I would prefer it to be done automatically and immediately but I can live with manually triggering it